# The inverse of the hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel

if I have 3 tables:

[image]

there is no direct relation between the factory and the order, so in can I want to get all orders from a factory I use the **hasManyThrough** relation.

```php
//Factory Model
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Order::class,
        Product::class,
    );
}
```

Now, how can I inverse the relationship?
how to get the factory from the order **without passing through the product**

```
$order->factory ✅ <-- I want this
$order->product->factory ❌
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasOneThrough`, in the `Order` model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneThrough;

public function factory(): HasOneThrough
{
   return $this->hasOneThrough(
      Factory::class,
      Product::class,
      'id',
      'id', 
      'product_id',
      'factory_id',  
   );
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it's not working

 `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_id' in 'field list' `

Comment: I edited my answer. Try changing the name of key

Comment: it gives wrong SQL query, 
`return Order::find(1)->factory `
will execute this SQL query:  `select factories.*, products.id as laravel_through_key from factories inner join products on products.factory_id = factories.id where products.id = 1 limit 1 `  witch is **wrong **

Comment: Are you sue? I tested on my local and it returns the right factory

Comment: The query is right. If produc_id of Order is 1, so where products.id = 1

Comment: A big thank you @KhangTran - that worked perfectly for me.